# What does T(n) is constant for n < 2 mean in recurrences?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am reading the book "Introduction to Algorithms" and I have this problem that is saying to derive the lower and upper bound for T(n) for the following recurrence :

```
T(n) = 36T(n/6) + 2n
```

And its saying assume that: T(n) is constant for n <= 2, can anyone explain to me the last sentence, what does that really mean?

```
assume that: T(n) is constant for n <= 2
```

Comment: Possibly that T(1) and T(2) is independent of n, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means `T(0) = c_0` and `T(1) = c_1` are constant proportional to `n` to notify that you should not worry about them and compute them as a constant in time complexity. If they are not constant, as they are the basis of the recurrent equation, you can't use the master theorem to analyze the complexity.

Suppose in real `n` is in the order of `10^20`, but `T(0) = 10^50`, and `T(1) = 10^60`. Hence, you can't compute the complexity using the master theorem.

Comment: Okay thank you but I have another question related to this, using the same assumtion I have to find also the T(n) = 12T(n/2) + n^2 * log n, so using the Generic Master Theorem I arrived at T(n) = O(n ^ 3.58496), should I leave the result just like this or does this mean that I have only found the upper bound O, if yes how should I find the lower bound Ω then?

Comment: @Dan The upper bound is correct, in this way. For \Omega case, you can easily say `T(n) = \Omega(n^2 * log n)` as we have this part currently in the equation.

Comment: I wonder if 'T(0) is not constant' has any meaning. Given that the only parameter to T is a constant 0, shouldn't T(0) must be a constant? Then the assumption is the question looks redundant.

Comment: @PetarPetrovic Did you see my example?

Comment: yes but both  10^50 / 10^60 are actually very large constant?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic if `n` is in the order of `10^20`, so they are not! Indeed, in real situations I mean.

Comment: Yes, in real world we need to take care of them. But I think this question is more about theoretical problem.

Comment: @PetarPetrovic If it is, it should be in TCS, not in SO. Anyhow, it is not, as the answer is accepted by the OP. And thanks for your comments.